# Como fazer o alerta do formulário de forma correta?

Tags: php, envio-de-email

Eu tenho um formulário de contato, portanto quando preenchido ele não esta exibindo o alerta de falha de envio ou enviado com sucesso, ele esta redirecionando para uma página de busca, aqui meu script:

```
<form class="form-inline" action="<? $PHP_SELF; ?>" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="nome">Seu nome (obrigatório):</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nome" name="nome" placeholder="Digite aqui seu nome...">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Seu e-mail (obrigatório):</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Seu email...">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="telefone">Seu telefone (obrigatório):</label>
        <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="telefone" name="telefone" placeholder="Seu telefone...">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="assunto">Assunto (obrigatório):</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="assunto" name="assunto" placeholder="Digite aqui o assunto...">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="mensagem">Sua Mensagem:</label>
        <textarea type="text" class="form-control" id="mensagem" name="mensagem" placeholder="Escreva aqui sua mensagem..." rows="5"></textarea>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="btnEnviarMensagem">Enviar Mensagem</button>
</form>

<?
if (isset($_POST['btnEnviarMensagem'])){
    // Passando os dados obtidos pelo formulário para as variáveis abaixo
    $nome    = $_POST['nome'];
    $emailremetente    = trim($_POST['email']);
    $emaildestinatario = 'comercial@melfort.com.br'; // Digite seu e-mail aqui, lembrando que o e-mail deve estar em seu servidor web
    $telefone = $_POST['telefone'];
    $assunto = $_POST['assunto'];
    $mensagem = $_POST['mensagem'];


    /* Montando a mensagem a ser enviada no corpo do e-mail. */
    $conteudo   = "Nome: $nome<br>";
    $conteudo  .= "Email: $emailremetente<br>";
    $conteudo  .= "Telefone: $telefone<br>";
    $conteudo  .= "Assunto: $assunto<br>";
    $conteudo  .= "Mensagem: $mensagem<br>";


    // O remetente deve ser um e-mail do seu domínio conforme determina a RFC 822.
    // O return-path deve ser ser o mesmo e-mail do remetente.
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.1\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
    $headers .= "From: $emailremetente\r\n"; // remetente
    $headers .= "Return-Path: $emaildestinatario \r\n"; // return-path
    if(mail($emaildestinatario, $assunto,  $conteudo, $headers, "-r".$emaildestinatario)){
        // echo "<strong style='color: green'>"."Sua mensagem foi enviada com sucesso!"."</strong>";
        //  echo '<script type="text/javascript">document.form1.reset();</script>';
        echo '
            <script type="text/JavaScript">
            alert("Sua mensagem foi enviada com sucesso. Obrigado");
            location.href="andreyferraz.php";
            </script>';
    }else{
        echo '
        <script type="text/JavaScript">
        alert("Aconteceu um erro, tente novamente mais tarde");
        location.href="andreyferraz.php";
         </script>';
    }
}?>
```

---

Quando eu clico em enviar ele executa o else dessa condição:

```
if ($resultados->num_rows > 0) {
    while($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($resultados)) {
        echo utf8_encode("<strong>Nome: </strong>" ."<strong>". $linha['nome']."</strong>" . "</br>");
        print ("<strong>Endereço: </strong>" . $linha['endereco'] . "</br>");
        if (isset($_POST['cidade']) && $_POST['cidade'] === 'sao-gabriel-da-palha') {
            $fromPerson = 'São Gabriel da Palha';
            echo "<strong>Cidade: </strong>" . $fromPerson . "</br>";
        }
        print ("<strong>Telefone: </strong>" . $linha['telefone'] . "</br>");
        echo "<strong>email: </strong>" . $linha['email'] . "</br>"."<hr>";
        if (isset($_POST['palavra'])) { // remover acentos
            $palavra = preg_replace("/&([a-z])[a-z]+;/i", "$1", htmlentities(strtolower(trim($_POST['palavra']))));
        }
        if (!empty($palavra) &&
            in_array($palavra, array('andrey ferraz', 'andrey', 'ferraz', 'andrey martins ferraz'))){
            require 'andreyferraz.php';

        }
        if (!empty($palavra) &&
            in_array($palavra, array('melfort'))){
            require 'melfort.php';

        }

    } }else{
   echo "<h3 align='center'>Empresa ainda não cadastrada!</h3>";
}
```

Comment: Esse segundo trecho de código que você enviou está sendo usado onde ?

Comment: na verdade o erro é nestes if encadeados com while e else, ta meio que uma salada de frutas isso

Comment: @Victor o que vc sugeri que eu faça, eu tbm acho que é esse o problema, sempre quando clico em ENVIAR acaba exibindo o else, "empresa não cadastrada"

Comment: este código está todo em uma única página ?

Comment: Não, a condição está em uma outra página, portanto eu estou fazendo o uso de Require

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eai amigo, encontrei alguns detalhes no codigo que podem estar causando estes erros.

Inicialmente em:

```
 <form class="form-inline" action="<? $PHP_SELF; ?>" method="post">
```

Dois Pontos..
Deve ser usado:

```
<?=$PHP_SELF?>
```

para textualizar uma variavel no output, além do que:

```
<form class="form-inline" action="" method="post">
```

Ja daria conta do recado, pois ao nao ter url de direcionamento, é redirecionado para a mesma pagina

Depois vejo outro problema em:

```
<? 
if (isset($_POST['btnEnviarMensagem'])){
```

Atualmente o PHP se inicializa com a tag

```
<?PHP
```

O que pode estar causando o conflito dentro das decisões.

Digo isso pelo seguinte.

Copiei seu codigo:
Alterei as decisões para if(true)..
Comentei as linhas de redirecionamento JavaScript

Testei:
O alerta() foi chamado nos dois casos da decisão: TRUE e FALSE, e também no conteúdo html seu script PHP apareceu como texto.

Modifiquei de

```
<?
//para 
<?php
```

O alerta foi chamado apenas uma vez e desta vez nenhum script PHP apareceu na tela.

Tente isso, pode ser este o problema, sei que não novas versões o php não iniciam com a tag simples.
Versão utilizada por mim do PHP: 5.2

Comment: Cara infelizmente não é isso, ja fiz as mudanças aqui que vc sugeriu, ele esta executando um else de uma outra função quando eu clico em enviar, n sei porque isso ta acontecendo!

Comment: Bom vamos la então:
1) Ele esta redirecionando para outra pagina? 
2) isso esta acontecendo via javascript ou php?
3) antes dele redirecionar para a função de mandar email em PHP ou depois?

Comment: Sim, ele esta redirecionando e executando um else de uma outra função, imprimindo a mensagem Empresa não cadastrada

Comment: provavelmente é problema na query do banco então, que não esta retornando nenhum resultado, de uma revisada nela.

Comment: Mais veja bem, pra fazer o envio do email eu não uso nada do banco de dados mano

Comment: @WPfan separe o php do formulario com o php que vai enviar o email.. no action coloque enviar_email.php  e coloque o código do envio lá..